# Python GAE Requests not returning cookies after get request

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-requests

I have written a project in python which I am now in the process of moving to google app engine. The problem that occurs is when I run this code on GAE:

```
import requests
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

def retrievePage(url, id):
    response = 'http://online2.citybreak.com/Book/Package/Result.aspx?onlineid=%s' % id
    # Set the timeout to 60 seconds
    urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(60)

    # Send the first request
    r1 = requests.get(url)

    cookies = r1.cookies

    print 'Cookies: %s' % r1.cookies

    # Retrieve the content
    r2 = requests.get(response, cookies=cookies)
    return r2.text
```

When running the code on GAE the cookies from the first request are missing. That is to say, `r1.cookies` is just an empty cookie jar. The same code works just fine on my django server where the cookies should contain a asp.net session id.

The reason i have two requests is because the first one redirects the user and will only retrieve the correct page if the session cookie is the same.

print output on GAE:

```
Cookies: <<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[]>
```

print output on Django:

```
Cookies: <<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[<Cookie ASP.NET_SessionId=dhmk1vt3ujgmhhhmbwsclukb for online2.citybreak.com/>]>
```

Anyone know what the problem might be? Is GAE stripping away the cookie information? I am also opened to any suggestions on another way to retrieve the page, i just found that the requests module was easier than the alternatives i found.

Answer (score 0):

I tried urlfetch it seems to be showing the cookie headers:

```
import logging
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

response = urlfetch.fetch(url)
logging.info(response.headers)
```

Comment: It seems that urlfetch does show the cookies headers. I will try using urlfetch instead of requests and see if that improves the situation. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

There's a PR (patch) available here: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/4044 for solving the issue you (and many others) have. Tested with GAE in production and development.